# CheckBox[] with onClickListener[]?

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox, boolean, listener

**EDIT: this question is mostly closed and the only problems i have with this code are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6230466/708685)**

For part of my app, I have a page of items that are represented as checkboxes, each with a associated boolean that eventually get collected and stored as a string as follows:

```
final CheckBox gas_oil = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.gas_oil);
gas_oil.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
    {
    if (gas_oil.isChecked())
        {
        impacts.append(getString(R.string.gas_oil) + " | ");
        anythingchecked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

this is extremely tedious and did not seem to be a very efficent way to do this since i have 9 or 10 items that users can check or not. also this method means that if they click and unclick something, that item is still in the `StringBuilder impacts` and that if they click it again then it is in there twice.

My solution was to have everything in arrays:

```
  String[] impactsn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);
  final boolean[] impactsb = new boolean[impactsn.length];
  final CheckBox[] impactsc = new CheckBox[impactsn.length];
  View[] impactsv = new View[]{findViewById(R.id.gas_oil),findViewById(R.id.ghost_fishing),findViewById(R.id.marsh_damage),findViewById(R.id.nav_haz),findViewById(R.id.shell_damage),findViewById(R.id.waste_pollution),findViewById(R.id.wild_entang),findViewById(R.id.other)};

  for (int i = 0; i < impactsn.length; i++)
    {
    impactsc[i] = (CheckBox) impactsv[i];
    impactsc[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                if (impactsc[i].isChecked())
                    impactsb[i] = true;
                else
                    impactsb[i] = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

unfortunately doing this causes the problem that (as far as i understand it) things within an `OnClickListener` have to be final. With the code as written, `i` can never be final, so I'm sort of at a standstill.

Should/can I have an array of `OnClickListeners` as well? Should I be calling to a method outside of the code I have here?

Also, below is the getter i was planning on using, I think that part will work just fine:

```
String getImpacts ()
    {
            String[] impactsn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);
    StringBuilder impactss = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < impactsn.length; i ++)
        {
        if (impactsb[i])
                    impactss.append(impactsn[i] + " | ");
        }
    return String.valueOf(impactss);
    }
```

**EDIT: this is the version of code im running with now:**

package com.citsci.mardeb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Impacts extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    int length = 7;
    boolean[] impactsb = new boolean[] {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    EditText    view;

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.impacts);
```

//      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
//          impactsb[i] = false;

```
  View[] impactsv = new View[]
     {
    findViewById(R.id.gas_oil),
        findViewById(R.id.ghost_fishing),
        findViewById(R.id.marsh_damage),
        findViewById(R.id.nav_haz),
        findViewById(R.id.shell_damage),
        findViewById(R.id.waste_pollution),
        findViewById(R.id.wild_entang),
        findViewById(R.id.other)
        };

  CheckBox[] impactsc = new CheckBox[length];

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
     {
     impactsc[i] = (CheckBox) impactsv[i];
     impactsc[i].setOnClickListener(this);
     }

}// end of onCreate

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
    {
  switch (v.getId()) {
     case (R.id.gas_oil):
        impactsb[0] =! impactsb[0];
        break;
     case (R.id.ghost_fishing):
        impactsb[1] =! impactsb[1];
        break;
     case (R.id.marsh_damage):
        impactsb[2] =! impactsb[2];
        break;
     case (R.id.nav_haz):
        impactsb[3] =! impactsb[3];
        break;
     case (R.id.shell_damage):
        impactsb[4] =! impactsb[4];
        break;
     case (R.id.waste_pollution):
        impactsb[5] =! impactsb[5];
        break;
     case (R.id.wild_entang):
        impactsb[6] =! impactsb[6];
        break;
     case (R.id.other):
        impactsb[7] =! impactsb[7];
        }
    }

String getImpacts ()
    {
    String[] impactsn = new String[length];
    Resources myResources = getResources();
    impactsn = myResources.getStringArray(R.array.impacts);
  StringBuilder impactss = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
        {
        if (impactsb[i])
            impactss.append(impactsn[i] + " | ");
        }
    if (String.valueOf(impactss) != "")
        impactss.insert(0, "Impacts: ");
    return String.valueOf(impactss);
    }
}// end of Impacts.class
```

Comment: You should look in to using HashMaps to store data like this. Perhaps you can explain what you are trying to do at a higher level? This doesn't seem like the right implementation to me.

Comment: haha well you could totally be right, i am making this all up as i go along. briefly, my app is supposed to be a sort of interesting version of this form [dhec form](http://www.scdhec.gov/environment/ocrm/D-0984.asp). when the user has completed the form, they click submit and the app gathers all of the information they have submitted into a string so it can be attached in an email and submitted. i have no idea what `HashMaps` are at the moment but i will look into developer.android.com and on here and see if those seems appropriate.

Comment: sorry about the sloppy formatting, i use tabs and SO uses spaces, its frustrating going back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use anonymous (inline) listeners in this case. Instead have your Activity implement the listener...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case impactsv[0].getId:
                impactsb[0] = !impactsb[0];
                ...
                break;

            // Add other cases here

        }

    }
}
```

Then all you need to do to set the listener is...

```
impactsc[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then test for which CheckBox has been clicked by using the View which is passed to...

`onClick(View v)`

Comment: wow... mindblowing haha thank you so much. i hate to ask you to spoon-feed me this but "Then test for which CheckBox has been clicked by using the View which is passed to... `onClick(View v)`" was a little confusing, is this how you meant:


    `@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < impactsn.length; i++)
  {
  if (v == impactsv[i])
      impactsb[i] = true;
  else
      impactsb[i] = false;
  }
 }`

sorry so sloppy ... i couldnt figure out how to format the code properly

Comment: hrumph ... after dinner. also perhaps this is me being greedy/impatient, but is there anyway to make `switch (v.getId()) {case findViewById(impactsv[0]): impactsb[0] = true;` work? also with your solution, what happens when the user clicks on something again to deselect it, is the a `toggle` for booleans? again, thanks so much, ill be back on in a couple hours

Comment: @hooraygradschool: See my edited case statement. Use the unary 'NOT' operator ( ! aka logical compliment operator) to toggle a boolean.

Comment: exactly what i implemented, thanks! next question, if you still have time/interest, is why does `String[] impactsn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);` cause my app to fail?

Comment: @hooraygradschool: Sorry, I don't know - that looks OK as long as the array exists in the correct location. Do you have any 'special' characters in any of the strings in the array? Apostrophes and quotation marks need to be 'escaped', e.g., \' or \"

Comment: haha oh yep, im dumb. the first element in the array was `Gas/Oil/Chemical Pollutants` im guessing it was less than thrilled to see the slashes, ill just replace them with dashes when i get off work.

Comment: @hooraygradschool: Yep that looks like it may well be the culprit. Good luck and thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: lamez ... still crashing on the same line `Impacts(ContextWrapper).getResources() line: 80
String[] impactsn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);`

Comment: @hooraygradschool: I'd recommend posting a new question along with the xml file with the strings (array).

Comment: [good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230466/problem-filling-string-with-string-array-from-strings-xml) thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

first you don't have to have them as final, you can declare them outsid of the function then you won't be asked to declare them as final.
second if you need to know the state of the checkboxes as they are changed you can add a listener to each one of them with different task of course, you can do it with a loop, and then this loop will call to another function that will have the tag of this chsckbox, and will react according to this tag.
If you don't need to know the state when they are changed you can check the state of them once you are done with this screen, with isSelected() method.

Hope this helps,
Best regards.

Comment: for the above question you can check which one is it by doing
if(v==checkBoxes[i]) do something

Comment: while im sure you might be right, it is hard to follow what you suggest without any code examples, perhaps you could edit the code i provided to match what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go a complete code for this just fill between for your needs :

public class mainA extends Activity
{
    CheckBox[] chbx;Button apply;

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{   super.onCreate(bundle);
    setMyChBx();apply=new Button(this);
    apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{   public void onClick(View v)
    {   if(chbx[0].isSelected()) setsomthing0();
        if(chbx[1].isSelected()) setsomthing1();
        if(chbx[2].isSelected()) setsomthing2();
        if(chbx[3].isSelected()) setsomthing3(); // and so on
    }
});
}

public void setMyChBx()
{   chbx=new CheckBox[25];
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
    {   chbx[i]=new CheckBox(this);
        chbx[i].setTag(new Integer(i));//tags for the checkboxes simply from 0 to 24 (24 included)
        chbx[i].setOnClickListener(new chBxOnclick());
    }

}
/*
 * here you have three options to create one onclick method to all of them or to create many onclicks for each on of them
 * or don't create onclick method for the checkboxes just check the state once it's all done like above
 * example for onclick for all of them
 */

public class chBxOnclick implements OnClickListener
{   public void onClick(View v)
{   switch((Integer)v.getTag())   
    {   case 0: dosomething();break;
        case 1: dothis();break;
        case 2: dathat(); break;
        .
        .
        .
        case 24: doFor24();break;
    }
}

}
```

}

Comment: BTW, i preffer the tag method, as in this way you sure that this is the correct checkbox, and no mixing is involved, something that might happened, also it's easier to understand excatly what you are doing.

Comment: hrm this is interesting, im looking at it now.

Comment: i like the tag thing, i implemented that. i do only need it to check the state of everything once, but i am more than a little unclear as to how you are doing that with the `apply` button. i am going to edit the code in my question to reflect what i am currently working with.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, two things, first i don't like to implement the onclick interface in my main activity, and in the other hand i assume that you are not writing an activity which function only for the onclick interface, in this way it's easy to make mistakes, just create a class or even like this :
setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){ public void onClick(){ @todo  }});

Comment: The second is for your question, well once you click on apply(may be submit or set) inside of this onClick method check the state of each one of them with the method isSelected(), and do the work that needs to be done according to each check box, probably each check box is responsoible for different thing, so each checkbox if checked or not will call to specific method to process this state(checked or unchecked).