# How do I use hash-maps correctly when programming for Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, hashmap

I was told that I have to use a hash-map to store radio buttons. (The buttons as the key and their state as value) but I am new to Java and Android so It's kinda confusing.

I have a choice test with multiple questions and yes or no answers and I want to count the yes answers.

Maybe it's some simple thing to do but I can't figure out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: in response to my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221242/checkbox-with-onclicklistener/6221341#6221341) someone suggested i use a hashmap also, but, like you, i am just beginning this and havent gotten around to reading up on it on (developer.android.com). im interested to see what people say

Comment: I don't know why I feel these are stupid questions. Newbie questions yes since I've only started for 3 months. I would also like an example code just to make things clear. I've been searching on this for 2 days and it's brain wrecking.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a reference to all of your objects to a collection and iterate over them checking whether they are checked and counting them up.

Alternatively you could register an onClick listener on all of the buttons and increment/decrement a count when they are clicked.

There are multiple ways you could achieve this. I dont see why you need a hash map though, as the checked state is available on the button object itself. Your hash is useless.

Comment: I did register onClick listener but it counts the number of clicks not the number of answers. That wouldn't be a problem if the user doesn't click more than once on a radiobutton ... but it is a problem since it is for my diploma and my teachers could ask me if this is implemented correctly (though they don;t know any java under android) . I asked about it and someone answered i should use a hash map but no one seems to give me a straight answer or an example on how I should do it. I'm kinda out of time