# problem filling string[] with string-array from strings.xml

Tags: android, arrays, string, resources

**EDIT: woah ... somehow i replaced this question with another one i was asking, glad there is this rollback feature**

this specific question deals with the getter from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221242/checkbox-with-onclicklistener/6221341)

```
public class Impacts extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    boolean[] impactsb = new boolean[] {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}-
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
...

    String getImpacts ()
    {
    String[] impactsn = new String[length];
    Resources myResources = this.getResources();
    impactsn = myResources.getStringArray(R.array.impacts);
    StringBuilder impactss = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
        {
        if (impactsb[i])
            impactss.append(impactsn[i] + " | ");
        }
    if (String.valueOf(impactss) != "")
        impactss.insert(0, "Impacts: ");
    return String.valueOf(impactss);
    }
```

with these errors:

```
Impacts(ContextWrapper).getResources() line: 80
Impacts.getImpacts() line: 78
```

the final bracket of the below code:

```
@Override
public Resources getResources()
{
    return mBase.getResources();
}
```

and this line of code respectively:

```
impactsn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);
```

here is my strings.xml (the relevent parts anyway)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="impacts">
        <item>GasOilChemical Pollutants</item>
        <item>Ghost Fishing</item>
        <item>Marsh Damage</item>
        <item>Navigational Hazard</item>
        <item>Shellfish Damage</item>
        <item>Waste Pollution</item>
        <item>Wildlife Entanglement</item>
        <item>Other</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

i originally had the first item as:

```
<item>Gas/Oil/Chemical Pollutants</item>
```

but fixed that, hoping that would at least change the error if not fixing the problem. but nope, same error. any help would be vastly appreciated, im not terribly familiar with the use of array, especially getting resources for an array.

Logcat for exception:

```
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905): at com.citsci.mardeb.Impacts.getImpacts(Impacts.java:79)
```

Comment: @hooraygradschool: Is the getImpacts() method part of an Activity or a helper class?

Comment: it is part of a class that extends the activity, i added that to the top in response to your comment.

Comment: @hooraygradschool: Ok, if it's a method of your Impacts Activity then why do you have an override for getResources()? Just using getResources() should work fine - try commenting out your overridden getResources() method.

Comment: oh no i see your confusion, the overide and that block go with the `Impacts(ContextWrapper).getResources() line: 80` which is not part of my code, its part of the platform or source or whatever. sorry i didnt understand your questions/made an error in pasting the code to here.

Comment: @hooraygradschool: OK, I get it now - I can see that in the ContextWrapper source. Try separating your line of code into two in order to see what is causing the failure, i.e., Resources myResources = getResources(); impactsn = myResources.getStringArray(R.array.impacts);

Comment: ok that lead to the same failure in the `ContextWrapper` but was sort of helpful, the problem is apparently with the line `Resources myResources = getResources();` is it because this isn't my primary activity or something? or do i need to `extend` or `implement` something at the beginning? should i try making my own `getResources` method?

Comment: @hooraygradschool: Did you make any progress on this? I can't think of a reason for why getResources() whould fail. Can you post the actual logcat output for the error/exception?

Comment: i dont know how much can be gathered from it anyway though, it seems to me to be saying the same as the debugger. is this what you were talking about:

`06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
06-05 23:02:30.792: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.citsci.mardeb.Impacts.getImpacts(Impacts.java:79)`

Comment: @hooraygradschool: I added the logcat from your comment to your question. I'm still a bit stumped and I'm not sure if it will help but try prefixing `this.`, i.e., `this.getResources()`.

Comment: didnt seem to have any effect. thanks for adding the error to the question, im not sure why i didnt think to do that. so far, all ive been able to think about is a couple of sloppy fixes, which might or might not (probably not) work. ill post those attempts as i try them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i know this is poor coding, apologies in advance. so to fix this problem, i moved

```
String[] impactsn;
impactsn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);
```

to my main activity and made it static. now i refer to it within my Impacts class as `(MainActivity).impactsn[]`

i know this is not how you are supposed to share objects between classes, but it seems to be the easiest way so far. this is yet another reason why i am regretting my decision to make all of my tabs seperate activities. if you have any suggestions or advice on how to fix this code without using static references or on reasons why all of my tabs should be the same activities, please chime in.

Answer (score 1):

suggest not to define an array in advance, and used directly without defining a variable

```
mAutoComplete.setAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.OmskStreets)));
```

and more..

in Class

```
private String[] mStreets = null;
```

and in onCreate method

```
mStreets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.OmskStreets);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't define anything about UI before onCreate().

Moreover, the following is a poor coding example, but it works.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
     super.onCreate(icicle);
...
...
...
     COUNTRIES  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.COUNTRIES_ARRAY);
```

Comment: `super.onCreate(bundle)` was within the ellipses in my code. i have added it so it is apparent. im not sure what this answer adds to my question.